# Toggle function not giving required result

Tags: jquery

this jquery code is hiding the button than changing the text?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hide_show_b').toggle(function() {
        $(this).text('show');
    },function() {
        $(this).text('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you using ?

Comment: Deprecated http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. Sorry ! Calling toggle means you are toggling the current state of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toggle()` is deprecated in newrs version

> This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in
>   jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle()
>   that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the
>   event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

[**SEE HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: so which method do i use for running above code using jQuery 2.0.2